# ActionBar library based on ICS code

Tags: android, android-actionbar

Is there some library that:

1. Brings ActionBar API to pre-Honeycomb Android versions.
2. Is based on ICS open source code.

?

I know about Sherlock, but it's not based on ICS code.

Comment: What specifically are you expecting to get from the ICS source code?

Comment: I want it to look and behave exactly like ICS Action Bar.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The new version (in development) of ActionBarSherlock *is* based on ICS code. It will support split action bar, etc.

Comment: Great, looking forward to it.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a Google ActionBar implementation for pre-Honeycomb, take a look at the new [ActionBarCompat](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ActionBarCompat/index.html) sample.

Answer (score 0):

//Sample action bar layout

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/menu_refresh"
          android:title="refresh"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_refresh"
          android:orderInCategory="1"
          android:showAsAction="always" />
    <item android:id="@+id/menu_search"
          android:title="search"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
          android:orderInCategory="0"
          android:showAsAction="always" />

    <item android:id="@+id/menu_share"
          android:title="share"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_share"
          android:orderInCategory="1"
          android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText|collapseActionView" />
</menu>
```

//Insert following lines in your activity class where you want to show action bar

```
@Override

public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{     
 MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
  inflater.inflate(R.menu.action_bar, menu);
  return true;
}
```